# An UDP server with twistd plug in

Tags: udp, twisted

I am trying to add UDP socket server, listens to NB-IoT devices. My previous working experiences are only for TCP sockets.

EpicGpsUdpServer.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding: utf-8

from __future__ import print_function

import getopt
import os
import sys
import string
import struct
import binascii
import time
import uuid

from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor, defer
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi


class GpsPro(DatagramProtocol):

    def datagramReceived(self, data, addr):
        print("[Peer]{}:{}".format(addr[0], addr[1]))
        print("[Data]{}".format(data))
        if data:
            self.transport.write(data, addr)            

    # def makeConnection(self, data):
    #     pass

class GpsProFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return GpsPro()

def main():
    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
    reactor.listenUDP(5863, GpsPro())
    #reactor.listenUDP(5863, GpsProFactory())
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In order to use twistd to run it. I added

EpicGpsUdpServer_plugin.py

```
from zope.interface import implements
from twisted.application.service import IServiceMaker
from twisted.application import internet
from twisted.plugin import IPlugin
from twisted.python import usage
#from EpicGlinkUdpServer import GpsFactory
from EpicGpsUdpServer import GpsPro

class Options(usage.Options):
    optParameters = [["port","p", 5863, "The port number to listen on."]]

class GpsServiceMaker(object):
    implements(IServiceMaker, IPlugin)
    tapname = "Gps"
    description = "A UDP-based GPS server."
    options = Options

    def makeService(self, options):
        #return internet.UDPServer(int(options["port"]), GpsFactory)
        return internet.UDPServer(int(options["port"]), GpsPro)

serviceMaker = GpsServiceMaker()
```

If I run "twistd --help", the Gps will be listed as subcommand. If I run "twistd Gps", then it throws out errors like:

```
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800 Log opened.
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800 twistd 15.0.0 (/usr/bin/python 2.7.3) starting up.
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800 reactor class: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor.
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800 Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800   File "/usr/local/bin/twistd", line 5, in <module>
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800     pkg_resources.run_script('Twisted==15.0.0', 'twistd')
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 748, in run_script
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800     self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1517, in run_script
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800     exec(code, namespace, namespace)
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/twistd", line 14, in <module>
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800     run()
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 27, in run
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800     app.run(runApp, ServerOptions)
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/application/app.py", line 645, in run
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800     runApp(config)
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 23, in runApp
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800     _SomeApplicationRunner(config).run()
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/application/app.py", line 383, in run
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800     self.postApplication()
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/scripts/_twistd_unix.py", line 193, in postApplication
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800     self.startApplication(self.application)
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/scripts/_twistd_unix.py", line 381, in startApplication
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800     service.IService(application).privilegedStartService()
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/application/service.py", line 275, in privilegedStartService
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800     service.privilegedStartService()
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/application/internet.py", line 105, in privilegedStartService
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800     self._port = self._getPort()
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/application/internet.py", line 133, in _getPort
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800     'listen%s' % (self.method,))(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 373, in listenUDP
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800     p = udp.Port(port, protocol, interface, maxPacketSize, self)
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/internet/udp.py", line 114, in __init__
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800     self.setLogStr()
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/internet/udp.py", line 364, in setLogStr
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800     logPrefix = self._getLogPrefix(self.protocol)
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/internet/abstract.py", line 143, in _getLogPrefix
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800     return applicationObject.__class__.__name__
2018-03-14 14:16:41+0800 AttributeError: class GpsPro has no attribute '__class__'
```

**Questions**

Sorry, the UDP server brings many issues, which I want to make clear.

1. What is **class** attribute of my protocol?
2. Does UDP server protocol support factory? Since TCP server does support factory, I tried but I got some extra errors. In DNS server, twisted documentation shows it has factory, but I can not find reference code for raw UDP sockets.
3. Although UDP server is not connection oriented, but servers can write back with peer ip:port in a short time, within 1 minutes, in NBIoT devices, about 20 seconds. But since there is not factory, the code has nowhere to keep the context, like counterpart in TCP connections.

Any simple code/project will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is `__class__` attribute of my protocol?

If you have a class `Foo` then `Foo().__class__` is `Foo`.  This error happens because you're passing `GpsPro` instead of `GpsPro()` to `internet.UDPServer`.

> Does UDP server protocol support factory? Since TCP server does support factory, I tried but I got some extra errors. In DNS server, twisted documentation shows it has factory, but I can not find reference code for raw UDP sockets.

Twisted's UDP doesn't work with factories.  You just use a protocol instance.

> Although UDP server is not connection oriented, but servers can write back with peer ip:port in a short time, within 1 minutes, in NBIoT devices, about 20 seconds. But since there is not factory, the code has nowhere to keep the context, like counterpart in TCP connections.

You can create the state necessary for this on the protocol instance.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful. Now plugin and tac are both working.